# how to compare 2 json values in angular2

Tags: angular

Created the table by using jsonvalues in  ngfor in angular2+.i need to compare the id with other json and once it equals,need to check the checkbox inside the table.how can i do that?can any1 help me to resolve

Comment: please post some code that you have tried, or  any error message that you encountered

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Without code no one able to help you, please post code

Comment: working in office bro...wil create problem if i paste the code here

Comment: can u please explain  with below code and comments

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-container:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let a of jsonA">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let b of jsonB">
        <div *ngIf="a.id === b.id">
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

ng-container is rendered as a HTML comment so it doesn't disrupt your styling & structure, see [here](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue).

Comment: i will get the result as...... yes no no...if the innerloop length is 3

Comment: no no no....no yes no ....yes no no...no no yes...no no no.....5values for outerloop, 3 for inner loop.......note: no is for "!=" div ,yes is for "==" div

Comment: i need both equal div and not equal div

Comment: if i need equal div,ur code is correct,but i need both equal div and not equal div

Comment: Just use `*ngIf="a.id === b.id; else #template"` with the according template. Take a look into the docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else

Comment: it is not suitable for "ngfor"

Comment: from ur code ,we are getting 3 times the result...thats the problem here